# How to remove responsiveness of a Bootstrap 3 in only one div by ID

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple Bootstrap page-

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2" id="not_responsive"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I want is not making the div responsive having ID **not_responsive**.

What I have done in CSS is-

```
#not_responsive
{
    min-width : 500px;
}
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option of using "important" suggested by Rafael above will work.

Another way you can go is to be more specific in your css.  Here is an example:

*HTML:*

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2" id="not_responsive"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
```

*CSS*

```
.container .row #not_responsive
{
     width: 500px;
     min-width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Add important! to override TWBS Settings**

```
#not_responsive
{
    min-width: 500px !important;
}
```

Comment: Important can get you into to trouble.  This will work but I think you should try to target it by being more specific in your css thus not needing the important.

Comment: @w3bMak3r I am not a fan of `!important` either but considering he is using BS css file it might serve him best to use important for this situation.  Also consider that he could be getting his CSS from a CDN and in that case he won't be able to touch the css.

Comment: I upvoted you... I just feel kind of dirty every time I have to use that !important :)

Comment: @w3bMak3r thank you, yes I feel the same way.  It really is a terrible thing to do.  I think all developers cringe when they see it.

Comment: @AbrarJahin make sure your CSS reference in the HEAD is after TWBS css

Comment: @Abrar try just setting these as well: width: 500px;  max-width:500px;

Comment: @AbrarJahin that is strange.  In any case remove your col- class and it will work

Comment: It is working but destroy all other div's responsiveness